# groovy - why is jackson ObjectNode not truthful?

Tags: groovy, jackson

Why does this test case throw the exception "Node is not truthful" even though it's size is 1?

```
package foo.bar

import grails.test.*

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
import org.junit.Test

class MyTest{
    @Test
    void testJSonNode() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory())
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree('{"foo":"bar"}')

        assert node.size() == 1
        assert node.iterator().hasNext() == true

        if (!node) {
            throw new Exception("Node is not truthful")
        }
    }
}
```

Some background info:

1. The exception is not thrown if I change `if (!node)` to `if (node == null)`
2. I am guessing that this is an issue with [Groovy Truth](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Truth)
3. node is an instance of [org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/node/ObjectNode.html)
4. This used to work in org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.6.5
5. I am seeing this issue in org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11
6. ObjectNode implements Iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JsonNode` appears to define an [asBoolean() method](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html#asBoolean%28%29) so Groovy will call this to determine the Groovy-truth value of the object rather than using the general `!= null` test.  This method claims to be new in 1.9, which is why the behaviour would have been different in 1.6.5.

Comment: The groovy truth wiki page doesn't mention asBoolean(). Are there any other methods / interfaces that can contribute to a groovy truth apart from those mentioned on the groovy truth wiki?

Comment: @uklance since Groovy 1.7 it's all handled by `asBoolean` - the GDK adds an `asBoolean` method to `Object`, `CharSequence`, `Iterator`, `Collection`, `Map` and `Object[]` which implements the logic described in that wiki page, but any other class can provide its own.

Comment: Thanks @ian-roberts. This was a real head-scratcher for me